# actionscript: is there a control that can pick both date and time?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Just wanted to aovid reinventing wheels, I want the date and time picker, I know there is already a date only picker inside flash builder.

BTW: i am using flash builder 4

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this one :

http://strawberrypixel.com/blog/flexwheel-component-page/

http://strawberrypixel.com/flex/flexwheeltest/flexWheelTest.html